# Use lapply on subset of columns with written function?

Tags: r, apply, lapply, as.date

I have a dataset in which certain columns are dates in character form.
The dates are inconsistent in their formatting and missing data are present. I wrote a code to transform them in the correct format.
If I use the code for each column with lapply I have no issue.
When I try to implement the function to multiple columns at the same time the code gives me the following error: `Error in lout[w] <- *vtmp* : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments`

```
guess_date <- function(x){
  require(lubridate)
  if (!is.na(x)){
    result <- as.character(parse_date_time(x, 
guess_formats(as.character(x), c("mdy", "dmy", "dmY")))[[1]])
  }
  else {result <- NA}
  return(result)
}

df <- data.frame(a = c("12/01/1988","10/17/1999"),b = 
c("12/01/1988",NA))
df$a <- unlist(lapply(df$a , guess_date))
df$a<- as.Date(df$a, format="%Y-%m-%d")

cols <- c("a","b")
df[,cols] <- lapply(df[,cols], function(x){
  require(lubridate)
  if (!is.na(x)){
    result <- as.character(parse_date_time(x, 
guess_formats(as.character(x), c("mdy", "dmy", "dmY")))[[1]])
  }
  else {result <- NA}
  return(result)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I am missing something but looks like you have lot of unnecessary code. This works fine

```
library(lubridate)
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], parse_date_time, c("mdy", "dmy", "dmY"))

df
#           a          b
#1 1988-12-01 1988-12-01
#2 1999-10-17       <NA>
```

---

Moreover, all the dates in the `df` seem to follow the same `format` so `as.Date` works fine too.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("12/01/1988","10/17/1999"),b = ("12/01/1988",NA))
```

Comment: Thanks, the code works very well. Though, in my actual data I still have some dates that the code fails to parse:

`Warning message: 18 failed to parse`

How should I address this?

Comment: @MCS What is the format of the dates which failed to parse? We can add that format in `parse_date_time`.

Comment: The dates it fail to parse were double dates in a single cell.
The rest works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `anytime`

```
library(dplyr)
library(anytime)
df %>% 
     mutate_all(anydate)
#          a          b
#1 1988-12-01 1988-12-01
#2 1999-10-17       <NA>
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("12/01/1988","10/17/1999"),
          b = c("12/01/1988",NA))
```